# Trusted SQL 2008 Hyper-v connection to a IIS 7 Hyper-v & web.config's

Tags: hyper-v

I have 2 hyper-v machines

1. SQL 2008 Database VM
2. IIS 7 VM

I have setup a private virtual network between the 2 machines.

I can browse to one machines and log into it with that machines Admin password.

What I want to be able to do is set-up some sort of trust relationship between the VM's so that I do not get prompted for an Admin password when wanting to connect.

This is because in the web.config of a asp.net I simply want to be able to simply specify a Data Source=MACHINENAME for the SQL connection string

Is this possible and how do I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Thank you for steering me into the right direction Jake.
For anyone interested the link below might be helpful:
http://weblogs.asp.net/achang/archive/2004/04/15/113866.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't really about the VMs.  There's nothing about VMs or Hyper-V that has anything to do with what two OS-and-application-stacks in those VMs do when communicating with each other.

You'll need to do whatever you would have done to make an IIS machine and a SQL machine trust each other if they were both physical.